# Store initial state of element in variable

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to create a reset button to set the DOM back to its initial state after manipulation. Works perfectly on first use but after using it, once DOM is manipulated again I am unable to reset.

That is to say, after you click 'reset' in the below example it works the first time but not the second.

HTML

```
<p>some text</p>
<button class="reset">RESET</button>
<button class="change">Change DOM</button>
```

JS

```
$('button.change').on('click', function (){
  $('p').text('some new text');
});

$(document).data('initialState', $('p').clone(true));

$('button.reset').on('click', function (){
  $(document).data('initialState').replaceAll('p');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rk6pm/)

The value of initialState still seems to show the correct value after its first invoked but I cannot retrieve. Is there a way to make this work no matter how many times the example is reset?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am sure you have simplified your code to this bare bone format, but if you haven't and this is the issue, then you can change the text with a slightly different setup http://jsfiddle.net/rk6pm/2/

Comment: Seems like a really bad idea, but here's how you'd do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/rk6pm/3/

Comment: @gdoron my only objective here is to get the DOM back to its initial state before the manipulation that takes place due to user interaction. But still takes into account the events that take place on load.

Comment: @adeneo why do you think it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it. You can check updated jfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rk6pm/8/

It looks like that for some reasons (which are very obscure to me), `$(document).data` holding the cloned data of `$('p')` isn't retained after modifying again `$('p')`.

This might happen because of some internal jQuery behaviour, or because of how js GC works.

So what I did was moving the data cloning/storing function inside the click handler of object to be cloned/stored itself just before any other functions that will manipulate the element, so that it will clone and store anew the element (and its handlers) in `$(document).data`.

```
$('p').on('click', function (){
    $(document).data('initialState', $('p').clone(true));
    $(this).text('some new text');
});

$('button').on('click', function (){
  $(document).data('initialState').replaceAll('p');
});
```

It fixes that, but I'd really like to hear some js pro dev's opionion on this as I am not sure on the internal mechanisms which are implied (why does data of cloned element vanishes if afterwards we modify the original element? Does it really vanish? ...)

Also, on a side note, it might be that the approach I used, if used wrong (did I :) ?) could lead to some infinitely recursive/leaking behaviour... (couldn't it?)

Comment: This kind of solves the problem but not really. For instance if you click on the handler in the Fiddle more than once than now you've just cloned the altered state of the DOM. Making reverting impossible.

I am very curious on why the data isn't just retained as well...

Comment: well of course that served as an example, you are not supposed to mess with it :) Of course in a webpage, with a slightly more complex code, you could implement a way for avoiding that situation. And yes as I said the mechanism behind document.data retention has yet to be fully understood..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).data('initialState', $('p').clone(true));

 $('button.reset').on('click', function (){
    $(document).data('initialState').replaceAll('p');
 });
```

Replace To:

```
 var initialState = $('p').html();

 $('button').on('click', function (){
    $('p').html(initialState);
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ8zy/)

Comment: This won't copy data and events like `.clone(true)` does.

Comment: I've tried the solution but @Barmar is correct, I need the events copied over as well.